# Trouble Importing PHP Class within the same project

Tags: php, html, class, import, zoho

Someone could help me on the issue of referencing php files within the same project (calling classes) using "namespace","use" (  php v5.3 or higher)
[My Screenshoot][https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpqTn.png

> Fatal error: Class 'Zoho\CRM\Common\HttpClientInterface' not found in
>   C:\root\zohocrm-master\src\Zoho\CRM\index.php on line 73

```
  <?php namespace Zoho\CRM;

    use Zoho\CRM\Common\HttpClientInterface;
    use Zoho\CRM\Common\FactoryInterface;
    use Zoho\CRM\Request\HttpClient;
    use Zoho\CRM\Request\Factory;
    use Zoho\CRM\Wrapper\Element;    
                    .
                    .
                    .

public function __construct($authtoken, HttpClientInterface $client =null , FactoryInterface $factory = null )
        {
            $this->authtoken = $authtoken;
            // Only XML format is supported for the time being
            $this->format = 'xml'; 


             $this->client = new HttpClientInterface();
            $this->factory = $factory ;
            $this->module = "Leads";
            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your download link is broken. Please add the relevant pieces of code here and let us know what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Robinson, you are calling the class "Zoho\CRM\Common**HttpClientInterface**" from this position: "C:\root\zohocrm-master\src\Zoho\CRM**index.php**".

This means the way you are trying to use the namespace is not correct.

Remember, if you do:

```
use App\namespace\class_name
```

It means your class "class_name" has to be in a folder like this: App/namespace/. 
So define very well the path to your class when you are calling use.

Comment: Where I can define it?
PD:[Take a look this screenshoot](http://i.imgur.com/6GC4UUK.png?1)